# Linux/Java - Change Seed Source of SecureRandom

Tags: java, ubuntu, random

I have the following SecureRandom implementation:

```
public static int getSecureRandomInt(int min, int max) {

    int random = -1;

    try {

        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNG");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[512];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes);

        random = secureRandom.nextInt(max);

        while(random < min) {

            bytes = new byte[512];
            secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes);

            random = secureRandom.nextInt(max);

        }

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException noSuchAlgo) {

        System.out.println(" No Such Algorithm exists " + noSuchAlgo);

    }

    return random;

}
```

I now want that the destinantion of the seed is /dev/ttyACM1 (my Hardware RNG) and not /dev/random or /dev/urandom/. I already tried to edit the java.security file and set it via

> securerandom.source=file:/dev/ttyACM1

but that has somehow no effect. I would prefer to make a permamnent link from /dev/random and /dev/urandom to /dev/ttyACM1 permanently so that every application that uses this two locations for getting entropy uses automatically my Hardware RNG. My OS is Ubuntu 15.04.

Thank you for your support :)

Comment: "I would prefer to make a permamnent link from /dev/random and /dev/urandom to /dev/ttyACM1" : `rm /dev/urandom; rm /dev/random; ln /dev/ttyACM1 /dev/urandom; ln /dev/ttyACM1 /dev/random`. Not a programming question and you didn't need to post Java code if that was your question.

Comment: Does implementing a [Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html) help you maybe?

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. How can I recover the default random and urandom file in the /dev/ directory?

Comment: Instead of `rm`, use `mv /dev/urandom /dev/urandom.bak` etc. so you still have the old one. Or note the major and minor device number and `mknod` them back later. I suggest the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SecureRandom`'s `setSeed` method to supplement the "randomness" used by `SecureRandom` with arbitrary data, including data from `/dev/urandom` or some other nondeterministic source.